# Ropsten testnet connecting to fork before ropsten revival

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ropsten, blockchain-fork

I was syncing ropsten testnet using geth. Command used-

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "full"
```

At some time, `eth.syncing` returned-

```
{
  currentBlock: 353883,
  highestBlock: 1172714,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 353878
}
```

Notice the highest block. Its supposed to be 24xxxxx.
When I let it sync, syncing stopped at 1172xxx block. 
I checked blocks manually and compared them with http://ropsten.etherscan.io/ , blocks were same as [ethscan](http://ropsten.ethscan.io) upto 585000 blockNumber(and different afterwards), that is the block number where ropsten testnet revival took place from.
Now I assume that it somehow synced with a fork where revival did not take place.

1. Can anybody explain me how did it happen? Aren't all nodes on same fork?
2. How can I make sure when I start geth that it doesn't sync with blockchain from pre-ropsten revival fork?
3. Can something like this happen on main-net?

Comment: Which version of geth are you using? If you use a client older than 1.7.3 you may end in the pre-byzantinum fork.

Comment: I am using latest version(building from source)